# Try to further understanding the interface/module of OCaml

Tags: functional-programming, ocaml

I understand in OCaml there are concepts of `interfaces` and `module`.

And I understand how to use them now.

However, what I don't understand is how to fully utilise them.

---

For example, in Java, let's say we have a interface `Map` and we also have `Hashtable` and `HashMap` that implement `Map`.

In code, I can do like:

```
Map m = new Hashtable();
m.put("key", value);
```

Someday, if I change my mind, I can change to `Hashmap` very quickly by changing `Map m = new Hashtable();` to `Map m = new HashMap();`, right?

---

**But how can I easily do that in Ocaml?**

For example, I have `MapSig` and 'HashMap:MapSig`and "Hashtable:MapSig` in OCaml.

**How can I change the implementation easily?**

I don't think I can because in OCaml I have to do like:

```
let m = Hashtable.create ();;

Hashtable.put m key value;;
```

if I want to use `HashMap` instead, I have to replace every `Hashtable` with `HashMap` in the code, right?

---

### Edit:

I am not only seeking a way to make a alias to modules. I also consider the validity of implementations, i.e., whether the implementation follow the desired interface.

For example, in above Java example, only if `HashMap` has implemented `Map` interface, I can replace `Hashtable` with `HashMap`. otherwise, Java compiler will complain.

but if I do `module M = Hashtable` in OCaml, and if `HashMap` does not follow `MapSig` and I replace `Hashtable` with `HashMap`, what will happen? I think compiler won't complain, right?

Comment: You can write `let module H = Hashtable` and use everywhere this H. To change module you will need to change just line.


Maybe your question was about something else? What I missed?

Comment: For your addon: `let module Hashtable = HashMap in` and go on

Comment: you should make this an answer, it's correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example that shows what I think you're asking for:

```
# module type HASH = sig type t val hash : t -> int end ;;
module type HASH = sig type t val hash : t -> int end
# module I = struct type t = int let hash i = i end ;;
module I : sig type t = int val hash : 'a -> 'a end
# module J = struct type t = int end ;;
module J : sig type t = int end
# module M : HASH = I ;;
module M : HASH
# module N : HASH = J ;;
Error: Signature mismatch:
       Modules do not match: sig type t = int end is not included in HASH
       The field `hash' is required but not provided
```

The extra "`: HASH`" specifies that the module must match the HASH signature (and it also restricts it to that signature).

Just as a side comment, I believe the OCaml module system is world famous for its expressivity (at least in module system circles). I'm still a beginner at it, but it is worth studying.

Comment: ah, ok, so I just force sig after the alias. I do `module M : HASH = I` instead of `module M = I`, right?

Comment: Jeffrey, do you mind looking at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15012728/any-simpler-way-to-implement-non-in-place-selection-sort-in-ocaml ?

Comment: Yes, that's right. (This just scratches the surface of the OCaml module system.)

Answer (score 1):

Since 3.12.1 OCaml allows this syntax for opening and aliasing modules:

```
let foo .... =
  let module HashTable = HashMap in (* magic is here *)
  let h = HashTable.create () in
  ....
```

So u just need to rename module what you are using where you are using it.

Comment: Can I do `let module HashTable = HashMap` in top level instead of `let...in`?

Comment: Yes. The syntax is: `module HashTable = HashMap` (no `let`).

Comment: But this is a kind of alias, right? It doesn't force the interface, right?

Answer (score 0):

The most direct correspondence between your Java example and OCaml is using a functor (what OCaml calls a static function from a module to a module). So suppose you have the following implemented in OCaml:

```
module type Map = sig
  (* For simplicity assume any key and value type is allowed *)
  type ('k, 'v) t

  val make : unit -> ('k, 'v) t
  val put : ('k, 'v) t -> ~key:'k -> ~value:'v -> unit
end

module Hashtable : Map = struct ... end
module HashMap : Map = struct ... end
```

Then you would write a functor like this:

```
module MyFunctor(Map : Map) = struct
  let my_map =
    let map = Map.make () in
    Map.put map ~key ~value;
    map
end
```

Then you would instantiate a module using the functor:

```
module MyModule = MyFunctor(Hashtable)
```

And voila, changing the implementation is a one-line diff because both the module implementations conform to the `Map` signature:

```
module MyModule = MyFunctor(HashMap)
```