# How can I keep polymorphism when using Array to implement Stack in OCaml?

Tags: functional-programming, ocaml

I am implementing a `stack` in `OCaml` using `array`.

I wish it to accept any types. Here is part of my implementation and my question is also about it.

---

```
type 'a stack = {mutable storage : 'a array; mutable n : int};;
let create () = {storage = Array.make 2 0; n = -1};;
```

---

So, above, when I define the type of my stack, it is fine. the `storage` is a `'a array` which is an array accepts any type.

But when I implement the `create` function, I met the problem. How can I initialise an `'a array`? I can't, right? I have to give an initial value for it when I create it, right?

---

**Then how can I create a stack using array with polymorphism?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `storage` field is mutable, so you can put different arrays there at different times. So you can initialize with an empty array, which is fully polymorphic (like an empty list).

Another approach is to use an option type for the `storage` field and create your array at the first push operation.

I sometimes encounter problems of this sort in my production code. I usually end up using an option type.

(An even better approach is to use a list for the stack. Unless you need to access elements other than the top, the array is only causing trouble and not giving any benefit.)

**Update**

Here's a function that returns an array twice as big as the supplied array. For flexibility, the extra elements aren't guaranteed to have any particular value (though in fact they're just copies of the 0th element of the original array).

```
let double array =
    let len = Array.length array in
    if len = 0 then array  (* 2 * 0 = 0 *)
    else
        Array.init
            (2 * len)
            (fun x -> if x < len then array.(x) else array.(0))
```

Comment: How to make an empty array? I can't see it in the API of Array

Comment: Ah, ok, I understand, you mean a [||].

Comment: ok, what if I have to resize the array? How can write my `resize_array old_ary new_len`? say, this function is to create a new_len array and copy all the elements from old_ary

Comment: In Java, I guess using Array for Stack implementation is faster, right? However, using array in Java, we have to double its size if array is full. I am just trying to implement the same thing in OCaml to practise my OCaml skill.

Comment: If using option, then I have to write match storage with None -> ... | Some ary -> ...?

Comment: Also, Jeffrey, could you please look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15004147/try-to-further-understanding-the-interface-module-of-ocaml?

Comment: I added code to resize a non-empty array, but it isn't particularly idiomatic in OCaml. (As a side comment, I'd respectfully suggest that it might be good to look for the new things in OCaml rather than reproducing Java techniques. There are many enlightening things in OCaml, but not as many in the part that intersects with Java.)

Comment: @JacksonTale: in Java, when you create an array, you also have to create it of a certain type. I believe you are referring to an array of `Object`, which is a type that accepts all reference types (not primitive types however). So for the same thing in OCaml, you would need a type that is similarly compatible with lots of types.

Comment: For what it's worth, OCaml has parametric polymorphism, which doesn't work like Java inheritance. You can easily write a function (like `double` above) that works for any array of any type. JT is asking how to write similarly polymorphic functions for manipulating stacks. (OCaml also does have inheritance in its OO subsystem.)

Answer (score 2):

Why would you implement a stack using arrays in OCaml? That makes no sense, this is not C++ or Java. An immutable stack:

```
 type 'a stack = Empty | Stack of 'a * 'a stack

 let pop = function
   | [] -> raise (Invalid_argument "empty stack")
   | x :: s -> x, s

 let push x s = x :: s

 let is_empty s = (s = Empty)
```

Mutable stack:

```
type 'a stack = 'a list ref

let create () = ref []

let pop s =
  match !s with
    | [] -> raise (Invalid_argument "empty stack")
    | x :: xs -> s := xs ; x

let push x s = (s := x :: !s)

let is_empty s = (!s = [])
```

P.S. Before you claim that arrays are somehow going to be faster, you should perform tests.

Answer (score 1):

You could allocate the array lazily:

```
type 'a stack = {mutable storage : 'a array option; mutable n : int}
let create () = {storage = None; n = -1}
```

Your push function would then check whether the stack is initialised already and create the array of not.

However, on a more general note, I think you're better of defining your stack with an 'a list ref. Or even better, use an immutable stack, i.e. a list.

Comment: If I do an immutable stack, then for pop I have to return a tuple, not just a value, right? Even the official Stack module is not immutable.

Comment: That, or you separate the ``pop`` from the ``top`` function. The 'official' stack module is mutable because immutable stacks already trivially exist in form of the ``'a list`` type. ;)