# Does sort function in OCaml use immutable or mutable data structure?

Tags: functional-programming, ocaml

Does OCaml use `mutable` or `immutable` data structure in implementation of sort?

For many sort algorithms, we need to exchange data between positions in list or array or something.

I am just wondering, if OCaml is always intended to use `immutable data structures`, then each exchange operation will create a new copy?

Will that impact the `performance`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> For many sort algorithms, we need to exchange data between positions in list or array or something.

Not necessarily.

> I am just wondering, if OCaml is always intended to use immutable data structures

No, OCaml has both mutable and immutable data structures. Using immutable data structures is generally preferred though.

> then each exchange operation will create a new copy?

That would depend on the data structure in question. But generally you wouldn't want to express your sorting algorithm in terms of swapping individual elements when working with an immutable data structure (and as I indicated above, you certainly don't need to).

`List.sort` for example works on an immutable data structure (lists) and is perfectly efficient. It uses the merge sort algorithm (in current implementations of OCaml).

Comment: Hi sepp2k, I am currently trying to implement many sorting algorithms for practice of OCaml. For example, if I want to implement insertion sort for a list, then how can I do that? insertion sort involves data exchange, right?

Comment: by the way, sepp2k, do you remember one night, you helped me with my stupid question about type in sig/interface? I was totally lost in learning OCaml. But I am happy now that I stepped in the door, just need deeper understanding and practice about OCaml.

Comment: @JacksonTale Insertion sort requires inserting an element between two existing elements - not swapping. That's O(n) per insertion (for a total of O(n^2) because you have n insertions) even in imperative languages.

Comment: it depends how you see it, say we have `D C B A`, then the steps are: `D C B A` -> `C D B A` -> `C B D A` -> `B C D A` -> ... I mean just swap one by one until the final place it should be. But anyway, my real question is that if I implement a sorting which require many exchanges, does OCaml intend to do using immutable structure? If it is true, then in addition to O(n^2) insertions in your case, each time we need to copy all other elements to a new instance?

Comment: Let me ask in another way, why List.sort doesn't choose `quicksort`? Is one of the reasons that `quicksort` is bad for immutable list as it requires many exchanges?

Comment: @JacksonTale I didn't really understand most of what you just said. A sanely implemented insertion sort will have n inserstions, which each take O(n) time, leading to a total time complexity of O(n^2). And yes, you'll have to copy the list for each insertion, but as I said, there will only be n of them and each one is O(n) anyway, so the copying does not affect the asymptotic complexity. And if you want efficiency, you're not going to use inserting sort anyway.

Comment: @JacksonTale Quicksort doesn't require swapping. You can implement an O(n log n) quick sort just fine using immutable data structures. It's just slower (by a constant factor) than merge sort. Quick sort is only more efficient than merge sort when it's used as an in-place sort (which obviously it isn't when working on immutable data structures).

Comment: ok, we have n insertions, and each insertion takes O(n), then totally O(n^2) insertions, right? but for each insertions, we have to copy, and each copy takes O(n), so totally we would have O(n^3) not O(n^2) right?

Comment: @JacksonTale What? No. We have n insertions so we have n insertions. Period. The time it takes to perform one insertion does not affect how many insertions there are.

Comment: ah, ok, yes, u r right. yes, I was talking about in-place quicksort. Actually, in my question's `sort`, it is all in-place.

Comment: So in OCaml, we don't prefer in-place operations, right? because that will mean mutable, right? We just use extra space to store intermedia results?

Comment: @JacksonTale Right, we prefer immutable structures and those don't have in-place operations.

Comment: could you please also have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15004147/try-to-further-understanding-the-interface-module-of-ocaml?

Comment: do you mind looking at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15012728/any-simpler-way-to-implement-non-in-place-selection-sort-in-ocaml also?